# Is there away to allow capturing last and first name as well as expiry date using card.io on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, scanning, card.io

Using card.io, is there any possibility to scan last name, first name as well as the expiry date on iPhone?

Answer (score 3):

Dave from card.io here.

@digitup we are currently working on adding expiry scanning to the card.io SDK, but it is a slow and gradual research and development task. (See https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-source/pull/1 if you are curious.)

Scanning the customer's name is a much more of a challenge. No promises there!

Comment: how easy is it to add the additional classes ourselves?

Comment: @digitup if we knew how to do it easily, we would have already done so! But please feel free to jump into our open-source repo if you're interested.